# LilyPond: how to avoid staccato nullifying Fingering.add-stem-support?

Tags: lilypond

Consider the following code:

```
\version "2.24.2"
\language "italiano"

\relative do'' {
    \time 3/4
    <<
        {
            re4 sol-2 sol
        }\\
        {
            si,2.
        }
    >>
}
```

It renders this:

[image]

You can see how the fingering instruction nests neatly just above the note head. It changes if I add a staccato:

```
\version "2.24.2"
\language "italiano"

\relative do'' {
    \time 3/4
    <<
        {
            re4 sol-.-2 sol
        }\\
        {
            si,2.
        }
    >>
}
```

Suddenly, the fingering instruction is rendered above the stem:

[image]

Is there any way to place the fingering back above the note head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally both staccato and fingering indications are considered so called *Scripts*. When Lilypond needs to place multiple scripts on one Note Column the ordering depends on the *script-priority* value. The smaller this value the closer to the head a script will be placed. Staccato defaults to a script priority of -100, Fingerings to 100. So to place the fingering close to the head set the priority to something smaller:

```
\version "2.24.2"
\language "italiano"

\relative do'' {
    \time 3/4
    <<
        {
            re4 sol-.-2 sol
        }\\
        {
            si,2.
        }
    >>
}

\relative do'' {
    \time 3/4
    <<
        {
            re4 sol-.-\tweak script-priority #-200 -2 sol
        }\\
        {
            si,2.
        }
    >>
}
```